# CURLOPT_REQUESTFIELDS

Tags: curl

I have the following code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "IP_ADDRESS");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Cache-Control: no-cache',
                'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REQUESTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('email' => $email, 'passwd' => $passwd)));
// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

I am getting the error
Warning: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_REQUESTFIELDS - assumed 'CURLOPT_REQUESTFIELDS' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in...
Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be int, string given in...

Surprisingly, similar code on an old file in different same folder is working

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.

Its CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS instead of CURLOPT_REQUESTFIELDS